# Django & Celery - Accessing post_save data

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Celery task I'm attempting to call from a post_save signal.

Signal is:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender='foo.ModelClass')
def execute_after_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    special_task.apply_async(kwargs={'bar': instance.pk}, countdown=5)
```

Task is:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def special_task(bar, *args, **kwargs):
    bar = ModelClass.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=bar)
    print('Bar attribute: %s' % bar.attribute)
```

With this iteration, I get an error saying `special_task() got multiple values for argument 'bar'`. In iterations where I send just the instance.pk as an arg, I get a TypeError saying I need to pass an integer. And when my signal looked like:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender='foo.ModelClass')
def execute_after_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    special_task.apply_async(args=(instance.pk,), countdown=5)
```

I get an error saying a ModelClass with that attribute `DoesNotExist`.

I've looked at the other SO questions about this but I keep getting the same errors. Using Django 1.11.4, Celery 3.1.25 on Python 3.5.

This task is eventually trying to select a newly saved ModelClass, perform additional work on it, and then save it again. How can I do this?

[EDIT: Here's my stack trace:]

```
[2017-09-19 12:31:01,275: ERROR/MainProcess] Task projectname.foo.tasks.special_task[476904d9-78ed-489f-a47e-2c38fe8c64c9] raised unexpected: TypeError("special_task() got multiple values for argument 'bar'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brandon/projects/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/brandon/projects/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: special_task() got multiple values for argument 'bar'
```

Comment: The `special_task.apply_async(args=(instance.pk,), countdown=5)` is correct, please provide the full traceback of exception you get after this. The only issue i foresee is that in task you are doing `print('Bar attribute: %s' % bar.attribute)` the `bar` is a pk not an object instance perhaps you meant `link.attribute`

Comment: I corrected above, and posted the stack trace.

Comment: Provide traceback for this error `ModelClass with that attribute DoesNotExist`

Comment: I changed the code back and I get this traceback: https://gist.github.com/brandonjschwartz/172925a7e416ceb76c904fd03e60b412  I will have time to see where I went wrong in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the most recent traceback you have provided, when you are using `bind=True` the first argument for the task should be `self` see [Bound tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks):

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def special_task(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
    bar = ModelClass.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=bar)
    print('Bar attribute: %s' % bar.attribute)
```

Comment: Thank you, this answered a few questions outside of this one as well!